# AFMotion HTTP GET request syntax for setting variable

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

## My goal is to set an instance variable using AFMotion's AFMotion::HTTP.get method.

I've set up a Post model.  I would like to have something like:

```
class Post
  ...
  def self.all
    response = AFMotion::HTTP.get("localhost/posts.json") 
    objects = JSON.parse(response)
    results = objects.map{|x| Post.new(x)}
  end
end
```

But according to the docs, AFMotion requires some sort of block syntax that looks and seems to behave like an async javascript callback.  I am unsure how to use that.

I would like to be able to call

`@posts = Post.all` in the ViewController.  Is this just a Rails dream? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, the base syntax is async, so you don't have to block the UI while you're waiting for the network to respond.  The syntax is simple, place all the code you want to load in your block.

```
class Post
  ...
  def self.all
    AFMotion::HTTP.get("localhost/posts.json") do |response|
      if result.success?
        p "You got JSON data"
        # feel free to parse this data into an instance var
        objects = JSON.parse(response)
        @results = objects.map{|x| Post.new(x)}
      elsif result.failure?
        p  result.error.localizedDescription
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Since you mentioned Rails, yeah, this is a lil different logic.   You'll need to place the code you want to run (on completion) inside the async block.  If it's going to change often, or has nothing to do with your Model, then pass in a &block to yoru method and use that to call back when it's done.

I hope that helps!

Comment: You're the man, thank you.  For anyone who else might stumble across this, the key is the async.  The ViewController is going to load before the data returns, so you have to (1)initialize your data variable blank, and then (2) reloadData once the async returns.

Comment: Exactly. So many things in RubyMotion-iOS are asynchronous, so get used to this pattern. :)